# Why am I getting TypeError: User.findByIdAndUpdate(...) in my code? MERN stack

Tags: javascript, mongoose, axios, passport.js, mern

I am trying to implement code to let users change their profile pic via updating a URL in mongoDB Atlas. here is the code for the route that should be reached on the press of a button:

*changepProfilePic.js*

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/user.model");

router.put('/', (req, res, next) => {
        const id = req.user._id
        const update = {$set:{image:req.image}}
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, {new: true})
(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router
```

Here is the relevant routing code in server.js:

```
const changeProfilePicRouter = require("./routes/changeProfilePic");
app.use("/api/changeProfilePic", changeProfilePicRouter);
```

here is the user schema:

*user.model.js*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    googleId: {
      type: String,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      minlength: 3,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    email: String,
    image: {type: String, default: 'https://i.imgur.com/Geb0OcA.png'},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    tps: {type: Number, default: 0},
  },

);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Here is a component with an axios function to go to the first route on button press:

*changeProfilePic.component.js*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Button, Form, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

function HookChangeProfilePic() {
  const [profilePicSrc, setProfilePicSrc] = useState("");

  const changeProfilePic = () => {
    Axios({
      method: "PUT",
      data: {
        image: profilePicSrc
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "/api/changeProfilePic",
    }).then((window.location.href = "/profile")).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form className="m-0">
        <Form.Row className="justify-content-md-center m-4">
          <Col xs="auto">
            <Form.Control
              onChange={(e) => setProfilePicSrc(e.target.value)}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Image Src"
            />
          </Col>

          <Button variant="warning" onClick={changeProfilePic}>
            Update Profile Picture
          </Button>
        </Form.Row>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HookChangeProfilePic;
```

I am using Passport.js for authorization

sorry if i am missing any relevant code or informtion! I'm not trying to be lazy with my question, I just don't know what is important to show. I can quickly edit and add more stuff if needed.

I have checked the solutions to other questions that were similar to mine (that I could find) and none of them have helped so far.

Comment: The full text of the error is important to post. `TypeError:` includes a number of different error types. It's likely due to the `(req, res, next);` you have dangling on the next line, but hard to tell.

Comment: A full error message would help a bit, at the moment it's a bit hard to determine.

Comment: oh gosh, it was the dangling (req, res, next); at the end. I feel so stupid. thank you.@HereticMonkey